# What does a dynamic-pressure loss coefficient of more than 1 mean (for eg air going through bend)?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, hvac

Air flow (eg in a duct) has a dynamic pressure, and when the air flow goes through e.g. a 90°-bend the bend has a dynamic-loss-coefficient.
The dynamic-loss-coefficient is used to calculate the total-pressure-loss by the formula:
Total Pressure loss = C * Velocity Pressure
(Velocity pressure is a different name for dynamic pressure. Both Total Pressure loss and velocity pressure are in Pascal, while dynamic-loss-coefficient C doesn't have a unit.)

For most bends/structures C is less than 1.
*What I don't understand is what a C greater than 1 actually represents/means in the real world?*
(Does it mean the air turns backwards?)

(Because if you subtract the total pressure loss from the dynamic pressure it would be negative.)

(Since this also has practical relevance there are several organizations empirically determining/collecting these values (e.g. ASHRAE and SMACNA), and in most cases C<1, but there are quite a few cases where C>1. E.g. an [example](https://i.imgur.com/Ai8CX4F.png) of an fitting by SMACNA and an [example](https://i.imgur.com/w6YoDbC.jpg) by ASHRAE. (Edit: [Heres](https://i.imgur.com/Tt0NKCv.png) an image of the definitions and formulas used by SMACNA.)
But the examples are just for illustration and don't matter in themselves, i'm just interested in what happens to the airflow when C>1.)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $C$ coefficient simply quantifies the pressure loss of a restriction as a scale multiple or fraction of the dynamic pressure $\frac 1 2 \rho v^2$. But the dynamic pressure is usually much less than the total pressure of the flow.

For example, air flowing at 10 m/s at a static pressure of 10 atm has a dynamic pressure of

$$ \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{10}{1} 1.22 ~\rm{kg/m^3} \right)(10 ~ \rm{m/s})^2 = 610 ~\rm{Pa ~ or} ~0.006 ~\rm{atm} $$

which is far less than the static pressure of 10 atm.  So your flow could lose many times the dynamic pressure going over restrictions and still have plenty of pressure left at the end.  There is nothing special about the loss coefficient $C$ being greater than one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
How is it determined(/is there a very rough approximation or some principle) how much of the lost total pressure is static-pressure and how much of it is dynamic pressure?
(1/3)

Comment: Like say first you have just the duct and it ends straight. And then you have the same duct, but you add a bend/fitting as its end.
There is now some total-pressure-reduction (as calculated by multiplying C times velocity-pressure). This total-pressure-reduction needs to be equal to the sum of static-pressure-change and dynamic-pressure-change, right? (2/3)

Comment: But how much of the total-pressure-reduction is "archived" by reducing the dynamic-pressure and how much by reducing/changing the static pressure? Is there a very rough rule?
(Presumably with the same fan blowing the air through it, but now the bend adding some air-resistance the air is going at least a little slower through the same diameter, so there is likely at least some dynamic-pressure reduction.) (3/3)

Comment: The pressure losses are entirely in the static pressure, because the flow rate and therefore average velocity must be the same everywhere along the pipe, or it would violation continuity (mass conservation).  In a constant area set of piping, if you had different avg velocity (=(flow rate)/area) at different stations of the pipe, that would mean either fluid is accumulating in an area, or voids are opening up, which cannot happen

Comment: For a system with *variable* cross sectional area, it's a little different because there is trade off between static and dynamic pressure. E.g. if the diameter expands, the velocity (and thus dyn pressure) will decrease, while the static pressure correspondingly increases. But I would still basically consider losses as being "deducted from" the static pressure. Total amount of expected losses in the system are what determines the pressure your pump or compressor driving the flow must operate at to achieve the required flow

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.   

If i understand it correctly the answer is based on the pump or fan being picked/adjustable to archive a certain flow.   
___  
But let's say the fan (model and rounds per minute) was fixed. If one now added the bend at the end of the duct the flow-rate/air-velocity (in the entire duct, not just at the bend)  would decrease a bit (due to the increased air resistance), or? (1/2)

Comment: So if the size of the duct stays the same and air-velocity would decrease, this is the same as saying dynamic-pressure drops. But likely static-pressure would also decrease somewhat. 
___So is there some principle or very rough rule of thumb that says how much of the total-pressure-decrease would be dynamic-pressure vs total-pressure (when the fan was fixed/doesn't get stronger to archive the same flow-rate with more resistance)? (2/2)

Comment: @user84635 by "archive" do you mean store?

Comment: You are talking about a couple different things here. 1) In a flow condition where the pump and piping is all fixed with a given flow rate, if you measured the static pressure directly upstream and downstream of a bend, the battle downstream would be slightly lower, while the flow rate and dynamic pressure would be the same at each point.

Comment: 2) if you take that system and add more resistance to it, while keeping the same pump with the same power, then the pressure being produced by the pump (static pressure just downstream of the pump) will increase, and the flow rate will decrease. What stays the same is the *Power* output by the pump, which is a function of flow rate times pressure.

Comment: If you are familiar with electrical circuits, and the relationships between power, current, voltage, resistance, and voltage drop, it is exactly the same relationship between power, flow rate, pressure, resistance, and pressure drop. Conceptually at least, if not precisely mathematically.  This is known as the Hydraulic Analogy.

Comment: Thank you especially 1 is very clarifying.

Is power (=flow rate times pressure) staying the same when changing the pipe/duct, but otherwise keeping everything the same also true for fans?
E.g. in this fan-curve https://i.imgur.com/GLQdtHD.jpg it seems at least total pressure (and maybe also power) generated can vary, or? (1/2)

Comment: (The fan-curve (eg curve 3) shows the fan always at the same amount of rotations per minute/*the fan itself is unchanged in the whole graph*, but varying how much resistance there is against it. So at 60Pa resistance it would produce ~300 m3/h, while at 50 it would produce roughly 120m3/h.) (2/2)